# How to create a list without using range in Python (For Loops)?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, foreach, range

Let's say I have

```
myString = "ORANGE"
```

How can I write a for-each loop that lists each character so it looks like this

```
1O
2R
3A
4N
5G
6E
```

I am confused as I don't know how to do it without using range.

Comment: "But as a list so everything goes down vertically and not across." => ??? Sorry but I don't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 2):

This is quite basic. 5 answers and none of them actually say this I am surprised.  Never mind this should do what you asked for:

```
myString = "ORANGE"
a = 1

for i in myString:

    print(str(a) + i)
    a = a + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = "ORANGE"
l = [str(i)+j for i,j in enumerate(myString,1)]
' '.join(l)
```

Output:

```
'1O 2R 3A 4N 5G 6E'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, character in enumerate('ORANGE'):
    print('{}{}'.format(index + 1, character))
```

Python docs on [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do this:

```
myString = "ORANGE"
for i in range(0,len(myString)):
    print (str(i+1)+""+myString[i])
```

Without using `range`:

```
myString = "ORANGE"
j=1
for i in myString:
    print (str(j)+""+i)
    j+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
myString = "ORANGE"
for id, val in enumerate(myString, 1):
    print("".join(str(id) + val))
```